# Ragged right with hyphenation if and if there is an hyphen in the word

Tags: horizontal-alignment

The standard \raggedright prevent any hyphenation at all. The `ragged2e`or similar method through manipulating the right file allows all hyphenation. Is there a way to set raggedright, but a word that already has a hyphen in it can be breakup, but normal word won't be hyphenated at all?

Comment: There's no inhibition to breaking lines at explicit hyphens in `\raggedright`.

Comment: @egreg: That’s not correct: an explicit hyphen is charged an `\exhyphenpenalty` of 50.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Is that an inhibition?

Comment: No, @egreg, strictly speaking it is not; but you know perfectly well what I meant, you explained it in your answer (+1, by the way :-)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX charges line breaks at explicit hyphen the current value of the `\exhyphenpenalty` parameter, whereas “implicit” hyphens (hyphens that TeX inserts automatically during hyphenation) are charged a penalty given by the current value of the different parameter `\hyphenpenalty`.  So, all you need to do is to define a variant of the `\raggedright` declaration that zeros the former parameter, but not the latter:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\YZraggedright}{%
    \raggedright
    \exhyphenpenalty 0 % space is intentional
}
\newenvironment*{YZflushleft}{\trivlist \YZraggedright \item\relax}{}



\begin{document}

In the normal setting, \( \verb|\hyphenpenalty| = \number\hyphenpenalty \) and  
\( \verb|\exhyphenpenalty| = \number\exhyphenpenalty \).

\begin{flushleft}
    Inside this environment,
    \( \verb|\hyphenpenalty| = \number\hyphenpenalty \) and
    \( \verb|\exhyphenpenalty| = \number\exhyphenpenalty \).

    This means that \TeX\ will never choose a line break at a word containing an
    explicit hyphen, like ``mother-in-law'', as we can see here:
    moooootheeeer-iiin-laaaww and faaaaatheeeeer-iiiiiin-laaaaaaawww (the break 
    will appeal to \TeX\ only if it makes the paragraph at least one line 
    shorter, see \verb|\linepenalty|).
\end{flushleft}

\begin{YZflushleft}
    Inside this environment,
    \( \verb|\hyphenpenalty| = \number\hyphenpenalty \) and
    \( \verb|\exhyphenpenalty| = \number\exhyphenpenalty \).

    This means that, this time, \TeX\ \emph{can} choose a line break at a word
    containing an explicit hyphen, like ``mother-in-law'', as we can see here:
    moooootheeeer-iiin-laaaww and faaaaatheeeeer-iiiiiin-laaaaaaawww (the break
    will appeal to \TeX\ only if it makes the paragraph at least one line
    shorter, see \verb|\linepenalty|).
\end{YZflushleft}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard `\raggedright` setting doesn't inhibit line breaking at explicit hyphens:

```
\documentclass{article}

% for showing what happens
\usepackage{showframe}
\setlength{\textwidth}{4cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
aaabbb abcdef-ghijklmno-pqr-stuv
aaa gggggg abcdef-ghijklmno-pqr-stuv
aaabbb abcdef-ghijklmno-pqr-stuv
aaa ggggg abcdef-ghijklmno-pqr-stuv
aaabbb abcdef-ghijklmno-pqr-stuv
aaa ggggg abcdef-ghijklmno-pqr-stuv
aaabbb abcdef-ghijklmno-pqr-stuv
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What happens is that breaking at hyphens is, at TeX’s eyes, less desirable than breaking at spaces. The result is that a short fragment before the explicit hyphen is likely to be pushed to the next line, rather than allowing a break at the hyphen. You can do

```
\newenvironment{hflushleft}[1][\exhyphenpenalty]
  {\flushleft\exhyphenpenalty=#1 }
  {\endflushleft}
```

so in the `hflushleft` environment the penalty for breaking at explicit hyphens can be changed. If you do

```
\begin{hflushleft}
<text>
\end{hflushleft}
```

the behavior will be the same as for the standard `flushleft`; with

```
\begin{hflushleft}[0]
<text>
\end{hflushleft}
```

or even

```
\begin{hflushleft}[-50]
<text>
\end{hflushleft}
```

you make breaking at hyphens “more desirable”. Experiment with these values and then decide what to add to `\raggedright`, which you can do by

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\preto{\raggedright}{\exhyphenpenalty=<value>}
```

For instance

```
\preto{\raggedright}{\exhyphenpenalty=0}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation. It's very helpful.